# combining output values in a file

Tags: python, count

I have a file having following sort of values:

```
123 9   
111 5   
12 1   
123 4   
12 4   
109 5   
12 4    
35 7   
111 4   
124 6
```

Now we have to generate an output which will be like:

```
123 13  
111 9  
12 5  
109 5  
35 7  
124 6
```

i.e. if a `value` present twice then during writing output we write the `value` only once and sum up the `count` of that `value`.
I thought it could be done using `defaultdict` function but i'm confused how to sum up the value.
please help.

Comment: Is this `homework`? If so you should use the tag. Also does the ordering of the output file matter?

Comment: Are there only a handful of values in the file, as in the example? If the list is huge, it could affect the answers provided.

Comment: @jamylak if it would have been a home work then i also would have been tagged it likewise. thanks for mentioning.!

Answer (score 4):

if you don't care aout the order of the elements, then you can user Karls method.

otherwise use a sorted dict:

```
import collections
data = [(123, 9), (111, 5), (12, 1), (123, 4), (12, 4),
        (109, 5), (12, 4), (35, 7), (111, 4), (124, 6)]

order = collections.OrderedDict()
for value, count in data:
    order[value] = order.setdefault(value, 0) + count
```

it's similar to using a defaultdict, which you can pass a function on construction that returns the default value for keys not found in the dictionary:

```
import collections
default = collections.defaultdict(int)
for value, count in data:
    default[value] += count
```

but in that case also the order of elements is not retained.

Comment: +1 Good solution, I guess this might be a reason why `dict.setdefault` and `defaultdict` coexist. *Note*: `int` would probably be better than using `lambda x: 0` for the `defaultdict`.

Comment: @abhisek it assumes that data is a list of tuples

Comment: @mata how could i be able to change data from a file(given in two columns) to the format mentioned by you..??please help..

Comment: @abhisek - come on, you could at leas try to do your homework yourself. ok, one last help: `data = [(int(i),int(j)) for i,j in [l.strip().split() for l in open('input.txt')]]`.

Comment: @mata here your code gives the list of [values] only, but we want both the columns. Please maintain the desired output format as mentioned in question...

Comment: come on, now i've really helped you enough. if you're not able to do some basic output formatting yourself then you should search a good tutorial and look it up.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `collections.Counter`. Something like

```
counter = collections.Counter()
for a, b in data: counter.update({a: b})
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the output may or may not be in the correct order. In his example the output keys were in their original order.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel code not working for me. showing error: too many values to unpack.

Comment: I assumed you already had the data parsed. I said "something like" and gave you a 2-line snippet for a reason. You're expected to think a little bit about it.

Answer (score -2):

use an `ordereddict` like

```
mydict = ordereddict()

try:
    mydict[val] = mydict[val] + additional_val
except KeyError:
    mydict[val] = additional_val
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but this usage of `defaultdict` is very untypical. You should use `defaultdict(int)`, then you only need the line inside your `try:` statement. (Also, the loop is missing.)

Comment: `defaultdicts` are made so you don't have to do this, even though you shouldn't need to do this with a normal `dict` either since you can make use of `get` or `setdefault`.

Comment: why wouldnt you do this with a normal dict?

Comment: `get` and `setdefault` can have default values too. Also `defaultdict` creates a value when you need it. So you don't need to check for `KeyError`.

Comment: cheers for clearing that up for me..maybe i need to read the manual more often.